# Flex and Javascript security implications

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I've been researching about Flex and it seems that it's possible to use JavaScript to interact with the Flash component. What I would like to know is if there are any security issues when doing this versus just building everything within the SWF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly define in your Flex code which Javascript functions to respond to.

Look at `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`

As for Security: there are mechanisms in place to keep things 'secure'.

> For local content running in a browser, calls to the ExternalInterface.addCallback() method work only if the SWF file and the containing web page are in the local-trusted security sandbox.

[For more info, read through the API](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)